# internal routing / proxy

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy

I have 1 computer with 1 network card installed. The network card has 10 IP addresses assigned to it. I have a windows desktop application running there. The application is basically a webbrowser making a call to 1 specific website.

What I want to achieve is for the webbrowser to change its source IP address (round-robin through the IP addresses available on the network card) every time I visit the website, so that the website sees 10 different external IP addresses with each visit.

To add to this, id like to have a scenario were two web browsers run concurrently through different ip addresses

I'm looking to do the application in C#. How do I do it? Or perhaps can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: How do I do it? Or perhaps can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Aha, so you want each request to come from a different IP address (of the pool of 10 you have, going back to the first when this is exhausted)? Interesting, but should be doable - at least it's possible to bind the client address to different available IPs in UN*Xen, so I'd say Windows has a similar mechanism...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to this question.  If you want the other website to see your address then you need to ensure there is no proxy because proxies by their nature hide your address.  Ensure all 10 addresses are public.  NAT isn't going to expose 10 different addresses either.

Assuming you are using Berkely sockets, you can loop through the logic to create the sockets and flip out the endpoints in whatever cycle you desire.

```
while(true)
{
EndPoint ourEP = new IPEndPoint(MyServerIPOne, serverSocketPort);
socket.Bind(MyServerIPOne);
socket.SendTo...etc
}
```

[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) on MSDN displaying how to connect via http.